# When I use a Google service with Api laravel

Tags: php, api, laravel-8, vps, grpc-web

Unable to create a FirestoreClient: The requested client requires the gRPC extension. Please see https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc for installation instructions.

Comment: I want to install gRPC on my VPS, what are the possible ways ?

Comment: Hi @lolobash, Welcome to SO. I think this question could attract answers from more people if it was written with a better structure. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some guidelines on how to write questions better.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `phpinfo()` for `gRPC` extension enabled. Instructions of how to enable it provided by your link.

Comment: How can I activate grpc on my VPS?

Comment: @lolobash use console and follow the steps provided at https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc for your OS